# How `instanceof` operator work in JavaScript, if we change the existing prototype of object?

Tags: javascript, object, instanceof, prototypal-inheritance

**I am learning how inheritance work in JavaScript** and came across following situation.

[image]

If we change `Ninja` prototype completely with new `Object` then we lost the connection with old prototype. Look at the below picture.

[image]

Here we loose the connection with old prototype and it's old constructor function. Then how  `ninja instanceof Ninja` assert to `true`? we don't have any direct connection with Ninja prototype.

Please tell me how `instanceof` operator find `Ninja prototype` on `ninja object` prototype chain?

Comment: attached pictures are taken from javascript for ninjas book.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc, try [ask]

Comment: @Naren in this case, the images come from a book which is the source of the confusion. Seems fair to use them here.

Comment: "*Please tell me how instanceof operator find Ninja prototype on ninja object prototype chain?*" - it doesn't. It looks for (and finds) `Ninja.prototype` on the prototype chain - nothing cares about the old prototype object which is not referenced by anything.